# Javascript Regex match expression inside expression? (SUM\(.*?\))

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regex to parse excel expressions, something very simple like this:

```
SUM(1;2;SUM(999);SUM(3;4);SUM(9))
```

The regex should match all the SUM functions, so I can parse them later.
So far this is what I have

```
(SUM\(.*?\))
```

But it doesnt match SUM(999), only the other SUM functions. Im fairly new to regular expressions so I dont know what I'm doing wrong. Can anybody help me?

Thanks!

[image: https://regex101.com/r/ge6TTJ/1/]

Comment: What should be the expected matches? Is that entire input string or part of it?

Comment: I need all the matches shown in the picture, plus SUM(999). My problem is... why isnt SUM(999) being matched?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SUM\([0-9\;]+\)?` this regex would show you every SUM expression without the need of enclosing paranthesis.

Code:

```
let data = "SUM(1;2;SUM(999);SUM(3;4);SUM(9))";
let match = data.match(/SUM\([0-9\;]+\)?/gm)
```

Result:

```
["SUM(1;2;", "SUM(999)", "SUM(3;4)", "SUM(9)"]
```

If you would like to fullfill enclosing paranthesis you can do something like that:

```
let data = "SUM(1;2;SUM(999);SUM(3;4);SUM(9))";
let match = data.match(/SUM\([0-9\;]+\)?/gm).map(r => r.slice(-1) === ")" ? r : r.concat(")"))
```

Result:

```
["SUM(1;2;)", "SUM(999)", "SUM(3;4)", "SUM(9)"]
```

Comment: FYI this doesn't match digits at the end `SUM(1;2;SUM(999);SUM(3;4);SUM(9);3;4)`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Regex world is pretty awesome.